# Stored Procedures Performance in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a SP in my database which I have reused from a previous question [Date Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates/#510239) to query a start and end date and return all days between the 2 dates which I then do a JOIN to my orders table.

For some reason the query with the SP takes over 40sec and under 3sec without with the SP.

I have done some research here and this answer suggests that the character set may have something to do it. [SP Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752922/mysql-stored-procedure-is-slower-20-times-than-standard-query/#16949603)

The collation connection and database collation state utf8_general_ci and latin1_swedish_ci respective, and the table collation for the table is latin1_swedish_ci.

Here is my sql

```
call make_intervals('2014-01-29 00:00:00','2015-03-03 00:00:00',1,'DAY');

SELECT
interval_start,
SUM(TenderedAmt) total
FROM time_intervals ti
LEFT JOIN tblorderheaders o
ON o.OrderDate = ti.interval_start AND ( ClientId=35 or ClientId IS NULL ) GROUP BY DATE(ti.interval_start) ORDER BY ti.interval_start ASC;
```

If I execute the following query it takes within 0.2sec without the JOIN to the table produced by the procedure.

```
SELECT SUM(TenderedAmt) total FROM tblorderheaders WHERE ClientId=35 AND (OrderDate>='2014-01-29' AND OrderDate<='2015-02-27') GROUP BY DATE(OrderDate)
```

Can anyone advise to why this query takes so long?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Mate, maybe not indexed and having a well populated table.

Comment: Thanks. I do have my orders table indexed by the primary key combination, OrderId and ClientId and also ClientId. Would it be worth indexing the OrderDate?

Comment: `ClientId=35`, is that 35 normally a passed variable in the stored procedure? ie `ClientId=@ClientId`

Comment: No, ClientId is not part of the stored procedure

Comment: Just so I am clear, it you run the `SQL` you posted normally it takes 3 seconds but if you put the EXACT same `SQL` (no variables etc) in a stored procedure it takes 40 seconds? And just to clarify you are using `MySQL`? `SQL-Server` is tagged as well.

Comment: The stored procedure table has only interval_start and interval_end. If that is what you are referring to?

Comment: sorry I am using mysql. I will remove the other tag.

Comment: here it is with out
`SELECT
SUM(TenderedAmt) total
FROM tblorderheaders
WHERE  ClientId=35 AND (OrderDate>='2014-01-29' AND OrderDate<='2015-02-27') GROUP BY DATE(OrderDate)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue!
The issue was the o.OrderDate was set to VARCHAR type. By changing it to a timestamp dramatically increased the query speed.